# Undo preference from third party module

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extensions, di, preference

I have to deal with a third party module that enthusiastically uses preferences for everything and breaks stuff with it.

#### For example:

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Censored\Censored\Model\Order"/>
```

To reduce the damage, I need to undo some of the preferences. Unfortunately they don't set the preferences for interfaces, but for concrete classes.

#### I've tried, in an own module:

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order"/>
```

But this results in an "Circular type preference" error. The Magento object manager will try to resolve the type again, find the preference, and so on.

What I actually need is a way to **remove** that original preference entry, without touching the files of the third party module.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: The one time I encountered this I ended up doing what Prachi posted below.  Even doing something like ObjectManager->configure() ends up with a circular preference error. So short of intercepting the merging process I believe it's either patching up the original di.xml from the extension or an empty class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your own class that extends Order class and does not make any changes. Like this:

```
<preference for="Censored\Censored\Model\Order" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order"/>
```

In your Vendor\Module\Model\Order :

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Order extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $orderItemCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface $invoiceManagement,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory $orderHistoryFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address\CollectionFactory $addressCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\CollectionFactory $paymentCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\History\CollectionFactory $historyCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\CollectionFactory $shipmentCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\CollectionFactory $memoCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\CollectionFactory $trackCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $salesOrderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productListFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $extensionFactory, $customAttributeFactory, $timezone, $storeManager,
            $orderConfig, $productRepository, $orderItemCollectionFactory, $productVisibility, $invoiceManagement,
            $currencyFactory, $eavConfig, $orderHistoryFactory, $addressCollectionFactory, $paymentCollectionFactory,
            $historyCollectionFactory, $invoiceCollectionFactory, $shipmentCollectionFactory, $memoCollectionFactory,
            $trackCollectionFactory, $salesOrderCollectionFactory, $priceCurrency, $productListFactory, $resource,
            $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
}
```